# C# Web Application - Run Async code from a sync function

Tags: c#, asynchronous, synchronization

In a web application When I Run Async code from a sync function
The code works Localhost
But not in the published version.

I get the error message "Thread was being aborted" in an old webforms solution when calling an Oracle Stored Procedure which sometimes takes time to run.
To avoid this I implemented the Fire and Forget pattern.
The problem is that all the existing code is sync.
So, I decided to try running an Async function from a sync function.

Said above............................

Comment: you have to show code

Comment: The most reliable way is to change the existing code to be async, all the way up the call stack.